# Need to convert this MySQL query to Laravel 4 DB Fluent

Tags: mysql, laravel

This will not convert to Laravel 4 DB Fluent.

```
$result = $this->database->query("
SELECT     node.title,
           node.title_slug,
           node.item_type,
           node.item_class,
           node.content,
           node.id                   AS id,
           node.lft                  AS lft,
           node.rgt                  AS rgt,
           (COUNT(parent.title) - 1) AS depth
FROM       menuitems                 AS node
           CROSS JOIN menuitems      AS parent
WHERE      node.menu_id   = '$menu_id'
AND        parent.menu_id = '$menu_id'
AND        node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY   node.id
ORDER BY   node.lft
");
```

Need to convert this to Laravel 4 DB Fluent.

Comment: What's the problem? Have you even tried to do it?

Comment: Yes I have been trying for a week now and people on the irc have tried converting it no matter how it is converted it gives a near error on the FROM, but yet it runs fine in MySQL. We have even tried DB:raw and it will not work.

Comment: In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise .. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that fluent does not have a cross join as of yet, only join and left join, you may want to inquire about getting it added for the next beta, ir perhaps see if there is another way to write it?

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('table_name')->join('another_table','on_condition_','on_operator','on_condition','cross’)->select(['item1','imtem2'.....]);
```